# Minimalist phased looping on Gibson Echoplex Digital Pro

Tags: guitar-effects, looping, looper-pedals, minimal-music

I'm working on live-looping minimalist music on a Gibson Echoplex Digital Pro feeding into a second looper, but one of the techniques I can't find a solution for is phased looping:

[image]

Both loops play simultaneously, but the top loop is in 8/4, and the bottom loop is in 9/4 with a rest at the end. The rhythms will shift in this cool way.

I'd like to play the phrase once live in 8/4, then copy it into an 9/4 cell in another looper so it's the 8/4 phrase plus a quarter-note rest. Then play the two loops together as they drift with the eighth notes synced. MIDI-synced looping is needed because otherwise, the eighth notes start flamming in very short order.

[Can Reich's Piano Phase be emulated with a delay unit?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/can-reichs-piano-phase-be-emulated-with-a-delay-unit) is not a solution because I want to create the phased phrases improvisationally and according to time signature, not tempo.

I'm also interested in other solutions if this isn't possible with the Echoplex. I could do this with fancy footwork through a MIDI controller on a laptop with a DAW, but I'd prefer an all-hardware solution, if possible.

Comment: Idk this looper, but can you set the tempo and quantise loops in the beat ?

Comment: @Tom if you mean by having two different BPMs--(n*8)BPM on one loop and (n*9)BPM--then no, you can't. The notes will flam without MIDI synch. Loopers that synch on the beat force the loop starts to synch. There may be a way to override this behavior in the EDP, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: It should be doable with a pair of MIDI-syncable Boss loopers, as long as a time signature of 1/4 or 1/8 is available. If you set something like 1/8 as the time signature i.e. measure length, you can have the loop lengths be any multiple of those 1/8 time units. 7/8 is 7 bars of 1/8, and 9/4 is 9 bars of 1/4.